# Shopify Private app API URL works in browser but not in API call using c#

Tags: c#, api, shopify

I am working with the shopify Private app API URL that works in a browser but not in an API call. I'm getting `{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}`

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var values = new NameValueCollection();
                var since = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                client.Headers.Add(values);
               var response = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://xxxx:xxxxx@abc.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json"));

                orders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShopifyApiObjects.SalesOrders>(response);
            }
```

Please help if anyone has an idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the authentication scheme look like for that API? You'll most likely need to pass in either a key (if it uses OAuth) or actual credentials.

Comment: In shopify we have both API key and Password in URL, so I think no need for Authentication

Comment: try passing the *apikey* and *api_password* through header data instead of in url.

Answer (score 1):

If your store has any sort of redirection the URL based authentication will be stripped out, so the API Password needs to be passed within the header of the request. Try adding:

```cs
client.Headers.Add("X-Shopify-Access-Token", YOUR_API_SECRET);
```

since I presume you are using `values` to build your query string.